# Understanding the rule of numpy.dot()

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I am trying to understand the following rule of numpy.dot() :

*"When a is N-D array, b is M-D array(where M>=2). The dot product is defindes as the sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b"*

What I want to understand is, how the calculation looks in detail for a specific example:

```
a = np.array([[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]],[[1,3,4],[7,1,2],[6,2,1]]])

print(a)

    [[[2 3 4]
    [5 6 7]
    [1 2 3]]

    [[1 3 4]
    [7 1 2]
    [6 2 1]]]

b = np.array([[1 , 2, 3],[4, 5 ,6],[7, 8, 9]])

print (b)

b = [[1 2 3]
    [4 5 6]
    [7 8 9]] 

np.dot(a,b) = [[[ 42  51  60]
              [ 78  96 114]
              [ 30  36  42]]

              [[ 41  49  57]
              [ 25  35  45]
              [ 21  30  39]]]
```

- How to I get the first value "42" of the dot product ?
- What is the last axis of a and what is the second-to last axis of b ?

I couldn't seem to figure out how to get the first value. I understood the other rules of the numpy.dot() definition, but not this last one.

Comment: Considering your matrix a as [a1, a2] format, the result of np.dot(a,b) seems to be [np.dot(a1,b), np.dot(a2,b)].

42 = 2*1+3*4+4*7  (row 1 of a1 dot column 1 of b)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum
> product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:

```
dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
```

In your example, `a` has shape (2,3,3) and the axis are (0,1,2). So the last axis of `a`  is 2. `b` has shape (3,3) and axis are (0,1). The meaning of second to last axis is penultimate axis. Since b has just 2 axis, the penultimate axis is 0.

Data along last axis of a: [2,3, 4]
Data along penultimate axis of b: [1, 4,7]

sum product = `sum([2*1,3*4,4*7])` = 42.

Same logic can be applied for all values of the output.

Comment: Thanks. So when I look at a: The first axis (axis 0) is the number of rows, here 2. The second axis (axis 1) is the number of columns in one row, here 3. And the third axis (axis 2) is the number of columns in one column of axis 2(axis 1), here 3. Did I get that right ?

Comment: @kayalotta yes that is correct understanding. In my answer every axis is mentioned by axis index.